# get values of two date.time lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are two lists

```
A=[datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 30, 0, 0)]

B = [[datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 25, 0, 0) 12]
 [datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 26, 0, 0) 19]
 [datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 27, 0, 0) 23]
 [datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 28, 0, 0) 24]
 [datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 29, 0, 0) 58]
 [datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 30, 0, 0) 70]
 [datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 31, 0, 0) 75]
 [datetime.datetime(2007, 8, 1, 0, 0) 100]]
```

How does it return the coresponing values of matrix B for only the date.times of list A?
The result could be the numbers of row of list B

```
[0,2,5]
```

or just the values

```
[12,23,70]
```

Comment: Is your Syntax is correct? I guess it should have comma(,) after datetime value.

Comment: `datetime.datetime(2007, 7, 25, 0, 0) 12` is a syntax error. Are they different items? If it's so you can just use a list comprehension `[i for i, (j, num) in enumerate(B) if j in A]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *list comprehension* and filter out the values not contained in `A`:

```
r = [val for date, val in B if date in A]
print(r)
# [12, 23, 70]
```

You can preferably make `A` a *set* to cut down the time for membership tests for each of the dates.

To get the indices of the matching items you can use `enumerate` in the list comprehension and collect the indices instead of the values.